# Where do I get the Boostrap Collapse plugin, and how do I set it up?

Tags: bootstrap-4

From https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/navbar/ :

> Navbars are responsive by default, but you can easily modify them to
>   change that. Responsive behavior depends on our Collapse JavaScript
>   plugin.

OK, that's great. Now where do I find that `Collapse JavaScript plugin`? That documentation page doesn't link to it, it's not mentioned anywhere on https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/download/ , and I can't find it with a Google search.

Comment: It's included in Bootstrap JS https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/collapse/

Comment: I saw that documentation page, but it also doesn't say anything about how to get the plugin or set it up.

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/collapse/#via-javascript
it's right there, as long as you're including the bootstrap js file it'll work

Comment: They're calling it a plugin, surely that means that I have to... plug it in, somehow. I know that I already have the basic Bootstrap JS included, because I'm using it for Bootstrap Modal dialogs and those work.

Comment: Again, [read the docs](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/collapse) which clearly explain usage.

Comment: I read the docs. That's why I posted them twice in my original question. The docs are misleading. They talk about "plugins" when they actually mean core functionality that isn't optional (the exact opposite of what "plugin" means).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded the `bootstrap-4.3.1-dist.zip` from https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/download/ and inspected the contents. Inside the `bootstrap.js` file, I found this:

```
var NAME$3 = 'collapse';
var VERSION$3 = '4.3.1';
var DATA_KEY$3 = 'bs.collapse';
```

Along with a bunch of other code that seems to implement the Collapse functionality.

So, on the hypothesis that the documentation is wrong and that these "plugins" are actually just core functionality, I double-checked my HTML. I found a structural error that was preventing the collapse functionality from working, introduced when we converted the plain HTML example to Slim syntax.

The `ul.navbar-nav.mr-auto` list of nav items was outside of the `#navbarSupportedContent.collapse.navbar-collapse` box that you're supposed to put it in.

So here's the (correctly structured) Slim version of the example from https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/navbar/ :

```
nav.navbar.navbar-expand-lg.navbar-light.bg-light
  a.navbar-brand href="#"  Navbar
  button.navbar-toggler aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label=("Toggle navigation") data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" data-toggle="collapse" type="button" 
    span.navbar-toggler-icon
  #navbarSupportedContent.collapse.navbar-collapse
    ul.navbar-nav.mr-auto
      li.nav-item.active
        a.nav-link href="#" 
          | Home
          span.sr-only (current)
      li.nav-item
        a.nav-link href="#"  Link
      li.nav-item.dropdown
        a#navbarDropdown.nav-link.dropdown-toggle aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" 
          | Dropdown
        .dropdown-menu aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown" 
          a.dropdown-item href="#"  Action
          a.dropdown-item href="#"  Another action
          .dropdown-divider
          a.dropdown-item href="#"  Something else here
      li.nav-item
        a.nav-link.disabled aria-disabled="true" href="#" tabindex="-1"  Disabled
    form.form-inline.my-2.my-lg-0
      input.form-control.mr-sm-2 aria-label="Search" placeholder="Search" type="search" /
      button.btn.btn-outline-success.my-2.my-sm-0 type="submit"  Search
```

So, the answer to my question is: just include `bootstrap.js`, and ignore everything in the documentation that mentions "plugins". If it doesn't work, there's a problem with the HTML structure or with the way that you're including `bootstrap.js`. If some of the "plugins" work but others don't, then it's definitely a problem with the HTML structure.

What the Bootstrap docs misleadingly call "plugins" are core functionality that comes with the library. They are not plugins in the normal sense (additional, optional functionality that you have to choose to include).